# Want to fix undefined index notice from this code

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is this and I want to remove following notices:

```
1. Notice: Undefined index: name 
2. Notice: Undefined index: website 
3. Notice: Undefined index: description
```

Also, this code adding data automatically when I refresh the webpage how to get rid of?

```
<?php
{    
     // Instructions if $ _POST [ 'name'] exists    
    }
    $wpdb->query("insert into ".PRO_TABLE_PREFIX."tutorial ( name, website, description )
    values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')");
    ?>
```

Comment: you need to insert the data only when there is a post action, hence first check whether there is a post action using if(isset()) then do the insertion

Answer (score 1):

You should use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

For example

```
if (isset($_POST['name']){
  echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

As a side note, read this article on the [$wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), looks like your code isn't follwing the guidelines there.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is check to see if the indexes you need, actually exists and is not empty, before trying to use them.

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['name'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['name'] ) &&
     isset ( $_POST['website'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['website'] ) &&
     isset ( $_POST['description'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['description'] ))
{
    $wpdb->query("insert into ".PRO_TABLE_PREFIX."tutorial ( name, website, description )
    values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')");
}
```

To get rid of the post being added again after refreshing, you could redirect to the same URL, after posting. This way it removes the POST from the URI.

```
header ( 'location : http://myDomain.com/myUrl.php' );
```

This redirect, would of course only get called, inside the if statement, we created before, and be the last thing you do with the POST.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in wp-content\plugins\pro-questions\admin-list-site.php`

Comment: yes the if statement `if ( isset ( $_POST['name'] && ! empty ( $_POST['name'] ) &&
     isset ( $_POST['website'] && ! empty ( $_POST['website'] ) &&
     isset ( $_POST['description'] && ! empty ( $_POST['description'] ))`

Comment: What's on the line before that code? Did you terminate that probably with the semicolon (;) ? The code I posted should not cause an error.

Comment: Edited the IF statement, please try it again.

Comment: I updated my answer, but you can have it again here: `if ( isset ( $_POST['name'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['name'] ) &&
     isset ( $_POST['website'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['website'] ) &&
     isset ( $_POST['description'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['description'] ))
{`

Comment: its working now but when i enter value it not submit in the table when again i submit blank data it populate the previous one

Comment: Sounds like an application error, and not with the check itself.

Comment: If you need to create the code for deleting and updating, you should probably make a new question for that.

Comment: You would have to create new code submitting a delete request, or an update request, and creating new query code. Search google how to do, or ask a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isset`for variable checking that those variables are assigned correctly or not.

And now Your Second problem that if you refreshed the page the same value is added to the database. After Submitting a Form Browser Keeps those value in there memory so if you try ignore this problem then do this:

```
  <?php
 {    
 // Instructions if $ _POST [ 'name'] exists    
}
$wpdb->query("insert into ".PRO_TABLE_PREFIX."tutorial ( name, website, description )
values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')");
header('Location:/path/to/your/file.php');
?>
```

Here After Adding the Value To database Your are redirected to the same page where all submitted variables are gone.